# Each element is the sum of itself with the next element of a List: now do this point-free in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Here it is the best I can do (I am a noob using Haskell):

```
map (\(y, z) -> y + z) (zip x (tail x))
```

I'm looking for a point-free solution.

Comment: "Each element is the sum of itself with the next element of a List", so in other words, `repeat 0`? :)

Answer (score 7):

Pointfree, eh? Let's ask lambdabot.

```
<DanBurton> @pl map (\(y, z) -> y + z) (zip x (tail x))
<lambdabot> zipWith (+) x (tail x)
```

Assuming that `x` is simply the input to this "function"

```
<DanBurton> @pl \x -> map (\(y, z) -> y + z) (zip x (tail x))
<lambdabot> map (uncurry (+)) . ap zip tail
```

Personally I'd go with the former; I'm not a fan of Lambdabot's gratuitous use of `uncurry` and `ap`.

Comment: The fact that Haskell has an IRC bot that can refactor Haskell code blows my mind. Well played sir.

Comment: The usage of lambdabot here is amazing. I would give you 10 ups, if I could!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `&&&` from `Control.Arrow`  (along with the `zipWith` trick from Dan's solution):

```
foo = uncurry (zipWith (+)) . (tail &&& id)
```